# Origin an realization of 2D magnetic materials

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, research-level, ferromagnetism

Recently, I encountered 2D magnetic materials. At first, I was a little bit surprised by the fact that one can have a 2D magnetic material because I thought of Mermin-Wagner's theorem, which states that in 2D continuous symmetries can not be spontaneously broken at finite $T$ in systems with short-ranged interactions (in the case of magnetic materials, short-ranged exchange interactions are responsible for magnetic ordering).

However, taking a closer look at the premise of the statement, I realized that making a system with magnetic anisotropy could solve the issue. I also found that there are several models where this has been established theoretically, for example Onsager found an exact solution of the Ising model with spin-dimensionality $n=1$ (that is only one relevant spin component) where you can have a phase transition to magnetically ordered state at $T>0$.

Let me turn back to the experimental part on how to realize 2D magnetic materials. I saw that 2D magnetic materials have most often been realized in chalcogenides (VdW materials) doped such that the Fermi level lies close to a 'van Hove singularity' such that the Stoner criteria $Ug(E_F)>1$ is fulfilled adn ferromagnetic ordering will occur. Now I have the following questions, relating to the experimental realization:

1. Relating the experimental realization of magnetic ordering in these chalcogenides back to the theory, we have that the doping is inducing magnetic anistropy?
2. What might be other ways to induce magnetic anisotropy? Trivial ways would be strain, gating, application of magnetic field, ... Are there other more exotic ways to realize this?
3. Now I understand that they are working with VdW materials because these are stable 2D materials (no dangling bonds etc.) but if we could achieve stable monolayers of heavy elements we could have 2D materials with intrinsic anisotropy (because of strong spin-orbit coupling)? Might this be a possible route?

PS. good references on the theory behind 2D magnetic materials is always welcome!